# Difference between Convert.ToDouble and double.Parse in correlation with InvariantCulture

Tags: c#, string, double, cultureinfo

I am wondering why this is working:

```
doubleValue = double.Parse(input[0].ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Replace(',', '.'), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

while this isn't:

```
doubleValue = Convert.ToDouble(input[0])
```

The point is, there are about 30 machines in one country (same Windows image, same hardware, different location). While the first 20 machines are fine with `Convert.ToDouble()`, the 10 other ones can't convert the values properly (They loose the decimal point in every case, no matter if point or comma).

Since the program is really big an complex, is there an opportunity to get `Convert.ToDouble()` working without changing the program itself?

Another point is, i tried different methods to convert my string value to a double, none of them are working but only the `double.Parse()`...

And also, is it *generally* bad to use `Convert.ToDouble()` vor strings? (Only for objects)

**Edit:**

I created this method inside my class:

```
public static double ToDouble(string value, IFormatProvider provider)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }

    return double.Parse(value, NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite | NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowThousands | NumberStyles.AllowExponent, provider);
}
```

and called it with (tried also points and commas):

```
doubleValue = ToDouble(myTextBox.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Result: Still not working...

Comment: "i tried different methods ..."  Including   `Convert.ToDouble(text,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` ?

Comment: You can either change your program or take control over the Regional settings of those 10 other PCs.

Comment: Yeah, i tried this for example: `doubleValue = Convert.ToDouble(myTextBox.Text.Replace('.', ','), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`. Also, it does not matter if it's point to comma or the other way round...

Comment: Which "Regional Settings" do you mean? They are the same. Or am i missing something?

Comment: Can you please show, with what parameters you've called that method, what you get and what you've expected to get?

Comment: And also you don't need to create that method by yourself, there is already same method in `Convert` class, only difference it's `string` parameter is `object` type.

Comment: Input (string): `465.09`, expected Output (double): `465.09`. But the result is `46509`...

Comment: I know, i implemented it for testing purposes only.

Comment: what is your `doubleValue` again, cause I'm testing it and result is `465.09`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156083/discussion-between-sem-and-essigwurst).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who run into such a problem, i finally figured out what the problem was.

Background: Some local IT guy installed a database client, which swapped the "decimal symbol" with the "digit grouping symbol" at the windows "region and language" settings.

However, the region / language itself wasn't changed, so it seems the program run into troubles here.

Replacing the "." with "," *may* additionaly cause problems if the string already contains a ".".

This problem could also be solved by asking the [CurrentCulture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [NumberDecimalSeparator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx), and the [NumbergroupSeparator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties and handle the string specifilcly then.

Answer (score 9):

As I remember, `Convert.ToDouble()` looks like this:

```
// System.Convert
public static double ToDouble(string value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
    return double.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

As you can see, internally it calls `double.Parse()` method, with `CurrentCulture`. So if you've got a string, and you expect it to always be a double, use double.Parse() with the culture you prefer.

P.S. Yeap, I was right, you can look in `mscorlib.dll` with ILSpy.

P.P.S I forgot about [ReferenceSource](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/) resource, so you can find out same thing [Here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,d98fcd7819f63d0f).

Answer (score 2):

`Convert.ToDouble` uses current thread culture so you cannot specify explicitly the culture you want to cast.

Whereas `double.Parse` provides you an overload to specify the culture you want to parse into, that's the reason why `Convert.ToDouble` is not working on some of your machines.

Comment: Is it possible to "sync" the culture on my machines? The point is, it's from the same windows image... Also, please see my comment in the question...

Comment: I don't think it would be possible to sync the culture of all your machines unless you do them manually, but anyways what I would prefer you to use is double.Parse(str, new CultureInfo("yourCulture")); as you will always know the required data will be in which format and you can easily format it.